# How to create loop in Python within cur.execute

Tags: python, sql, cursor

I'm very new to Python and am wondering how to create a loop so that the script can automatically ran with different Dates.

Currently my Python script is :

```
Date = '01Jan2021'

Query = """select distinct A.ID, count(A.Name)
           from A, B
           where Date between A.Start and A.End
           and B.Status='Y'
           Group by A.ID"""

def plan():
    try:
        cur = conn()
        cur.execute(Query, {'Date': Date})
        df = pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall())
        df.columns = [x[0] for x in cur.description]
        print ('Complete')
        Return df
```

Currently I need to change Date manually to extract the summary count in each month(e.g. '01Jan2021', '01Feb2021', ...,'01Oct2022'). After that, I can append  all together to show the historical trend. How to run it automatically instead of run it 20+ times?

Thank you!

Comment: `for date in ('01Jan2021', '01Feb2021', ...,'01Oct2022'): ...  cur.execute(Query, {'Date': date})`.

Comment: you should use join they are around for 30 years now

Comment: Thank you for your quick advice. where should I put "for date in ('01Jan2021', '01Feb2021', ...,'01Oct2022'):"

Answer (score 0):

```
Dates = ['01Jan2021', '01Feb2021', '01Oct2022']

Query = """select distinct A.ID, count(A.Name)
           from A, B
           where Date between A.Start and A.End
           and B.Status='Y'
           Group by A.ID"""

def plan(Date, Query):
    try:
        cur = conn()
        cur.execute(Query, {'Date': Date})
        df = pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall())
        df.columns = [x[0] for x in cur.description]
        print ('Complete')
        Return df


df = plan(Dates[0], Query)
for i in range(1, len(Dates)):
    df = pd.concat([df, plan(Dates[i], Query)], axis=0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm just getting a error message ' TypeError: plan() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Query'. Any advice?

Comment: @Ruyi If you're getting that TypeError then you're not using the code given in this answer. It is clearly passing 2 parameters to *plan()*. Having said that, the code in this answer is not runnable. You'll see why if you try it

Comment: @OldBill, wow thank you so much for pointing that out! To simplify my example query, I didn't put all my parameters above. I modified my query like your suggestions and now it all works! One more follow up questions: If I would like to show the Date column in the appended dataframe, how can I do that? I tried to modify the code in Query to select Date, but I received error message. Any advice? Really appreciate your help today.

Comment: @OldBill, nevermind, I found a typo. Thank you so much for your help today!!